# Resolving Linear Pointer is throwing error

Tags: blockchain, corda

I was trying to use `LinearPointer` in my Application.When I was trying to resolve the state data where I want the unconsumed latest version,it is throwing `Illegal Argument Exception`.I am adding the logs.

```
{actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyB, L=Tokyo, C=JP, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000004, flow-id=56a4acbd-971f-4e79-8b89-314a910de58a, invocation_id=b191db29-3ad2-4276-9136-217269398148, invocation_timestamp=2020-09-25T12:29:40.292Z, origin=internalShell, session_id=99a63055-16d6-4515-82e4-145399148cae, session_timestamp=2020-09-25T12:28:11.858Z, thread-id=160}
[WARN ] 2020-09-25T12:29:40,533Z [Node thread-1] interceptors.DumpHistoryOnErrorInterceptor. - Flow [56a4acbd-971f-4e79-8b89-314a910de58a] error - List has more than one element. [errorCode=1af3t2i, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5/1af3t2i] {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyB, L=Tokyo, C=JP, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000004, flow-id=56a4acbd-971f-4e79-8b89-314a910de58a, invocation_id=b191db29-3ad2-4276-9136-217269398148, invocation_timestamp=2020-09-25T12:29:40.292Z, origin=internalShell, session_id=99a63055-16d6-4515-82e4-145399148cae, session_timestamp=2020-09-25T12:28:11.858Z, thread-id=160}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: List has more than one element.
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.single(_Collections.kt:480) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
    at net.corda.core.contracts.LinearPointer.resolve(StatePointer.kt:197) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at statePointer.example.flows.UpdateVehicleFlow.call(UpdateVehicleFlow.kt:44) ~[?:?]
    at statePointer.example.flows.UpdateVehicleFlow.call(UpdateVehicleFlow.kt:28) ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:299) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:66) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
```

The code that I was trying is ,

```
val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
                null,
                listOf(vehicleState!!.state.data.serviceStationDynamic.resolve(serviceHub).state.data.linearId.id),
                null, Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)

        // Use the vaultQuery with the previously created queryCriteria to fetch the ServiceStation to be used as input
        // in the transaction.
        val serviceStationStateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ServiceStation>(queryCriteria).states.singleOrNull()
        val chargeFromDynamicPointer=serviceStationStateAndRef!!.state.data.serviceCharge
```

Answer (score 1):

The `linearId` of a `LinearState` is supposed to be unique for a particular state throughout its evolution. It means that when a linear state evolves all the historic states of it should share the same `linearId`. However, it needs to be unique for different linear states.

The error message suggests that you have more than one linear state with the same `linearId`, which is why resolve is failing.